# uboot using FIT to upgrade filesystem

Tags: u-boot

I want to upgrade my systems in the field using the uboot FIT images.

My system is a custom firmware, booted by uboot. So far the FIT filesystem works very good. It provides a shasum verified upload. I am using uboot scripts to update stuff on the target.

One intriguing type defined in uboot docs is type "filesystem". The actual content could be several things, like maybe tar'ed bunch of files, or an actual collection of separate individual files in one chunk in the FIT.

In another FIT question, Tom Rini implied that a filesystem is really just a binary blob. What goes into it is my problem and that uboot could then just mmc write ... or usb write ... to create the new filesystem on some partition. Is this really the case?

How can I build a filesystem (say FAT), on a host build computer for packaging with FIT?

Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creation of a filesystem image will depend on the filesystem itself.  In many cases, build systems such as OpenEmbedded or buildroot can help you here as they will create the images for you.

Comment: Hi Tom,Thanks for helping.  ss     dd if=/dev/zero of=fat.fs bs=1024 count=SIZE how big do you want the filesystem; specify it as SIZE * 1024.

mkfs.vfat fat.fs formats the file as the filesystem FAT  This will create a fs. If I put this in a FIT image with type filesystem - do I just mmc write to send it to a partition?

Comment: Yes, when you read that back out you will haev a FAT image in memory and can write it out.  If you have enough space in memory you could re-read back the contents off of disk and compare with your in-memory.